# Create GA4 property and webstream using code

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a property and webstream in GA4 using code. I have taken a look at the Analytics Data API, but my understanding is that this library is not capable of performing such a task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/create) is used for data extraction from GA4 properties.

In order to perform administrative tasks, have a look at [Admin API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest) and following are the methods you are looking for:

- [properties.create](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/create)
- [properties.dataStreams.create](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams/create)